# Form message validation using onsubmit function?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I'm making some message validation with javascript using `setCustomValidity()` method. So when I attach `onsubmit` in my form it won't display message in input field but when I use `onclick` it dispay message.I understand difference between `onlclick` and IonsubmitI function. But why message is not displayed when I use `onsubmit` function?

For example.

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="subForm">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    <input type="submit" name="subit" id="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var mail = document.getElementById("email");
        function subForm() {

            if (mail.value == "") {
                mail.setCustomValidity("Your input field is empty!");
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You will need to show us some code here ;)

Comment: Show some code we have no idea what you mean

Comment: I have added example above. Thank you in andvance. :)